# How do I size an element relative to the viewport whilst also 'capping' it's max and min size?

Tags: css

I have some text within p tags, and in my css I have:
    p { 
      min-width: 100px;
      max-width: 400px 
      font-size: 24vw;
    }

I would like the text to change in size depending on the viewport width, but to be constrained to a minimum and maximum width.

EDIT:
[Here is a working example](http://jsbin.com/mazuxe/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a dynamic font size based on viewport width, and have constraints on the maximum and minimum element widths, use the max/min-width properties to set the width limits, and the 'vw'(viewport-width) attribute to get a font-size unit relative to the viewport width.

Use the code as stated in the original question:

```
p { 
 min-width: 100px; 
 max-width: 400px 
 font-size: 24vw; 
}
```

The Original code I posted worked fine, I just had little experience with code at the time.

[Here is a working example](http://jsbin.com/mazuxe/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1):

**Used to this css**

**[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/m5ycg3F8)**

```
p { min-width: 100px; 
max-width: 400px;
 font-size: 24px; }
```

You have some missing in your css ...